# Possible to apply effects to the sound during a phonecall (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, audio, phone-call

So can I catch the sound input, and manipulate it before it "sends" to the phonemate?

Answer (score 4):

Apple does not provide public APIs to interact with a phone call. As BoltClock mentioned in his comment, it may be possible to use private APIs for this, but Apple would not allow a program that uses private APIs to be sold on the app store.

Comment: Do you think it will be possible to capture the audio of a phonecall? So no real interaction, but have a process running that captures all incoming sound?

Comment: This would definitely not be possible in the app store. Perhaps it's possible on a jailbroken device, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks GregInYEG, checked all possible references. It's indeed not possible. Sad, I really need that option...